# Proper code placement for logging entity specific warnings in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

My question is about proper and intended use of entities, repositories and logic code in symfony 2.

I have some logic that is specifically dedicated to the entity and so I put the logic code in that file. 1 thing that I would like to do is log specific warnings or debug information that occurs with this entity.

for example, these functions are in my entity:

```
/**
 * @return ArrayCollection|Humanoid[]
 */
public function getHumanoidPrimary()
{
    $humanoid = $this->getHumanoidByPersonType(Humanoid::TYPE_PRIMARY);
    if ($humanoid->count() > 1){

        //This is what I was planning to do
        $this->logger->warn('you should not have more than 1 primary.  there is a problem');

    }
    return $humanoid->first();
}

/**
 * @param $personType
 * @return Humanoid[]|null|ArrayCollection
 */
private function getHumanoidByPersonType($personType)
{
    //get the current step from the collection
    $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("personType", $personType));
    $humanoidsByType = $this->humanoids->matching($criteria);
    if ($humanoidsByType instanceof Humanoid) {
        return $humanoidsByType;
    } else {
        //todo: figure out how to log this warning.
        throw new \LogicException("No humanoid of personType:$personType Stored in property");
    }
}
```

Much of the documentation that I read says that entity code should not be aware of anything but itself and other entities.

So here are my questions:

1. What is the proper way to log warnings in symfony 2?
2. Is this the proper place for this code?
3. Should this code be moved to another class? Should it be a service?
4. Moving this to a repository does not seem right. repositories are for more complicated data requests and not for logic.  Is that correct?

These are noob questions, but it seems like I am fighting the code instead of using it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question because, after nearly two years of symfony2 development, I needed to stop an think about an acceptable answer.

Well

1. The proper way to log warning in symfony2 is `$this->logger->warning` so you were close to right solution.
2. If you want to follow symfony2 guidelines, you should never insert a snippet of code logic into entity class. I've never seen that into thirdy part bundles so I suppose that is a good practice to avoid this code inclusion into entity.
3. Usually for that kind of tasks I create a EntityNameManager (so in that case `HumanoidManager`) that basically I create as a service and use it along the entity
4. Yes, into repos should be placed only db-related code.

### Side questions

1. Don't be afraid of the number of Helpers/Managers. If you know that some functions can be implemented into a superclass, do it. Otherwise I don't think that this should be a problem (think about repository: every entity could (and if needed MUST) have his own). Moreover services aren't called (instatiated) any time before you use them. Of course I can't evaluate the xml or yml file processing time if this file increases, this could be interesting.
2. Well, I've seen that bundles use to place Managers into Entity folder itself. Otherwise you could do whatever you want: in that case naming convention (apart namespace declaretion and so on, of course) doesn't matter. If you want to separate Entity from his Manager, BundleName/Manager could be fine.
3. Personally, I use to inject logger into managers.

Comment: So most of the business logic code will go into helper classes like, "HumanoidManager".  Then I make that class a service. 
1. If I do that consistently, Will that "polute" the container space with numerous helpers classes and more importantly add significant processing overhead or delay? 
2. Which folder structure under /src/SCS/InquiryBundle do you suggest? bundle/Service, bundle/DependancyInjection, or bundle/Manager, or some other?
3. Do I inject the Logger into the class, or just make it ContainerAware and get('logger')

Comment: @ScottGutman: see my update, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Good question. My opinion:

1. Is not a good practice to have a logger into ad Entity: How do you pass it? Usually entity don't use any kind of service (logging also).

2/3/4. Entity don't know nothing about business logic. Repository are for business logic query. If business logic can grow and/or can interact with other system boundaries is better start with a service.

Hope this help

Comment: So most of the business logic code will go into helper classes like, "HumanoidManager". Then I make that class a service. 1. If I do that consistently, Will that "polute" the container space with numerous helpers classes and more importantly add significant processing overhead or delay? 2. Which folder structure under /src/SCS/InquiryBundle do you suggest? bundle/Service, bundle/DependancyInjection, or bundle/Manager, or some other? 3. Do I inject the Logger into the class, or just make it ContainerAware and get('logger')